# How to fix unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I get an error on line 11 of this code in Laravel saying:

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Here is the code of ClientController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Title as Title;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct( Title $titles) {
        $this->titles = titles->all();
    }

    public function di() {
        dd($this->titles);
    }
}
```

The Title:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Title extends ReadOnlyBase
{
    protected $titles_array = ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Dr', 'Mx'];
}
```

The ReadOnlyBase:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReadOnlyBase
{
    //
    protected $titles_array = [];

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->titles_array;
    }

    public function get( $id )
    {
        return $this->titles_array[$id];
    }
}
```

And the web.php:

```
Route::get('/di', 'ClientController@di');
```

I wrote the code exactly as a lynda lesson on Laravel, and yet I get an error.

Comment: `titles->all();` should be `$titles->all();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `$` here:

```
$this->titles = titles->all();
```

Change it to:

```
$this->titles = $titles->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
public function __construct( Title $titles) {
    $this->titles = $titles->all();
}
```

instead of

```
public function __construct( Title $titles) {
    $this->titles = titles->all();
}
```